# AJAX fails when it is moved to another js file in Django project

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have a code in index.html file:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{% url "myProject:load" %}',
    data: {val: document.getElementById('val').value, sections: secCols},
    success:function(json){},
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert("ajax error: load")
    } 
...
</script>
```

load is a function within views.py:

```
def load(request):
...
```

I move this piece of code into a js file in another folder. It produces an error after I move it.
Can you say how to fix it?

Comment: because in js file it can't use django template tag so your `{% url "myProject:load" %}` become useless, if you want to use the url write it path instead

Comment: this is a django syntax `{% url "myProject:load" %}`. if you are getting error here `'{% url "myProject:load" %}'`, then you need to create a variable in your html file and then use it in your JS. like `url = '{% url "myProject:load" %}'` and in JS, `url: url`.

Comment: ohh I see, can you put it as an answer @Nalin Dobhal?

Comment: well, someone already answered, you can accept that if it is working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable in your html:

```
<script>
var loadUrl = '{% url "myProject:load" %}';
</script>
```

And then use it in your js file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: loadUrl,
    data: {val: document.getElementById('val').value, sections: secCols},
    success:function(json){},
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert("ajax error: load")
    } 
...
```

Just make sure your js script is included *after* `loadUrl` has been defined.